# fetching data from fireStore to SQLite in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, sqlite, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to read All of the documents in the FireStore collection and fetch them in SQLite database. i implemented this process like this :

```
// instance of SQL controller 
DbController sqlController = DbController();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return scaffold (
    body : 
    //! button to start fetching 
        elevationButton(
            on tap: (){
                StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("orders").snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        int count = snapshot.data!.docs.length;
                        for(int i = 0 ; i< count ; i++){
                            Map<String , dynamic> model = snapshot.data!.docs[i].data();                        
                            int modelID = int.parse(snapshot.data!.docs[i].id);
                            sqlController.add(
                                CustomerModel(
                                    id: modelID,
                                    name: model["name"],
                                    phone: model["phone"],
                               )
                            );
                       }
                       return Container();
                    },
                );
            }
        )
    );
}
```

But how to fetch documents without streamBuilder

Comment: What reason is there that you don't want to use a stream? You can easily use the onDone method to get the end of the stream, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the documents from Firestore without using a `StreamBuilder`, you can use either the `get()` method for a one-time read, or the `listen()` method to listen for updates. The latter is actually what a `StreamBuilder` uses under the hood.

For examples of these see the Firebase documentation on:

- [Getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_6)
- [Listening to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart_3)